# How to invoke a broadcast receiver inside a background activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver declared inside an activity which is in background.I want this broadcast receiver to receive a message which i send from another foreground activity.I know that the activity should have been executed atleast once to register the broadcast receiver but that is not possible in my case.In my case that activity would have never been executed but still i want the broadcast receiver inside the activity to receive the message sent from other activity.Pls let me know if there is any way of doing it?